# IIS 7.5 app pool network drive access issue

Tags: iis, networking, pool, drive

I have two apps pools they both are .Net 4.0 app pools. If I switch my application to the second app pool then my application is able to connect to the network drive, If I switch the application to the first app pool I can't connect to the network drive from my application.

We created both these app pools about a month ago but we don't remember what did we do that cause the second app pool to work or the first app pool to break.

I also tried to create a new app pool and switch the application to this one and the application still can't connect the network drive. So, that means that by default an app pool doesn't have access to network drive, which is how it should be.

What can I do so that my first app pool has access to network drive.

Note:- Giving permission to app pool to access the network drive is not an option. We only have read access to the network drive.

Comment: I still have not got it working. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We actually found a temporary solution (might be the only one). We changed the app pool's identity to be the server user. Since the server user had access to network drive, the app pool and applications under it has the same access as the server user.

It might have some security flaws, but we are running intranet applications, so it might be ok.